# gazebo garden can't load material script

Tags: gazebo, simulation, gazebo-7

Environment:
$\space$ OS: Linux Ubuntu 22.04
$\space$ gazebo version: garden
Problem:
$\space$ I downloaded the sdf from [here](https://app.gazebosim.org/OpenRobotics/fuel/models/RoboCup%202009%20SPL%20Field), it is supposed to look like this
[image]
$\space$ but in my simulation it looks like this
[image]
I think it's caused by some errors when loading the matetial, in model.sdf the material element looks like this.

```
<material>
      <script>
        <uri>materials/scripts/</uri>
        <uri>materials/textures/</uri>
        <name>RoboCup/Carpet</name>
      </script>
    </material>
```

I read the Material.cc in sdfformat/src and I found that the script seems to have been implemented here.

```
if (_sdf->HasElement("script"))
  {
    sdf::ElementPtr elem = _sdf->GetElement("script", errors);
    std::pair<std::string, bool> uriPair =
        elem->Get<std::string>(errors, "uri", "");
    if (uriPair.first == "__default__")
      uriPair.first = "";

    if (!uriPair.second || uriPair.first.empty())
    {
      errors.push_back({ErrorCode::ELEMENT_INVALID,
          "A <script> element is missing a child <uri> element, or the "
          "<uri> element is empty."});
    }

    this->dataPtr->scriptUri = resolveURI(uriPair.first, _config, errors);

    std::pair<std::string, bool> namePair =
        elem->Get<std::string>(errors, "name", "");
    if (namePair.first == "__default__")
      namePair.first = "";

    if (!namePair.second || namePair.first.empty())
    {
      errors.push_back({ErrorCode::ELEMENT_MISSING,
          "A <script> element is missing a child <name> element, or the "
          "<name> element is empty."});
    }
    this->dataPtr->scriptName = namePair.first;
  }
```

so maybe there's something wrong in rendering? I wonder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gazebo Sim does not support the material script, this is mentioned in the [migration guide](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/migrationsdf.html).

The proposed alternatives are to either use plain colours, or to use textures.

Comment: I tried the pbr in material. But pbr do not have a scale element in sdf, is there any method to save this.

Comment: What I would do is to redraw that model in Blender, apply the texture, export as DAE and load the DAE as mesh in the SDF.